# json format in esp32 with arduino json

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, json

I am using an ESP32 module for bluetooth connection and scaning wifi network. But I cannot format the json using arduinojson library in the way I want.

```
void scanWifiNetworks() {
  //creating json
  DynamicJsonDocument jsonDoc(1024);
  char jsonBuffer[512];
  JsonObject wifiJsonObject = jsonDoc.createNestedObject("wifiList");
  wifiJsonObject["ssid"];
  Serial.println("scan start");

  // WiFi.scanNetworks will return the number of networks found
  int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("scan done");
  if (n == 0) {
    Serial.println("no networks found");
  } else {
    Serial.print(n);
    Serial.println(" networks found");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
//      Serial.print(i + 1);
//      Serial.print(": ");
//      Serial.print(WiFi.SSID(i));
//      Serial.print(" (");
//      Serial.print(WiFi.RSSI(i));
//      Serial.print(")");
//      Serial.println((WiFi.encryptionType(i) == WIFI_AUTH_OPEN) ? " " : "*");

      wifiJsonObject["ssid"] = WiFi.SSID(i);
      serializeJsonPretty(jsonDoc, SerialBT);
      serializeJsonPretty(jsonDoc, Serial);
      delay(10);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait a bit before scanning again
  delay(60000);
}
```

The output is like this

```
scan start
scan done
5 networks found
{
  "wifiList": {
    "ssid": "quark"
  }
}{
  "wifiList": {
    "ssid": "Airtel_Zerotouch"
  }
}{
  "wifiList": {
    "ssid": "NETGEAR77"
  }
}{
  "wifiList": {
    "ssid": "Itobuz-technologies"
  }
}{
  "wifiList": {
    "ssid": "Nokia 6.1"
  }
}
```

what I want is something like that

{
      "wifiList": {
        "ssid1": "quark1",
         "ssid2": "quark2"
     }
}

I know I am looping in a wrong way but could not figure it out. if possible please pointing out the right direction will help a lot.

Comment: crate array not object. `createNestedArray("wifiList")`

Answer (score 2):

You are repeatedly overwriting the `ssid` property of the same object.
Instead, you want to write different properties, like

```cpp
wifiJsonObject["ssid" + String(i+1)] = WiFi.SSID(i);
```

Then, only serialize the document once, when it is complete.

That being said, I strongly concur with Juraj in that the correct way to
represent a list in JSON (and `wifiList` is clearly meant to be a list)
is by using an array:

```cpp
void scanWifiNetworks() {
    DynamicJsonDocument jsonDoc(1024);
    JsonArray wifiList = jsonDoc.createNestedArray("wifiList");
    int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        JsonObject wifiNet = wifiList.createNestedObject();
        wifiNet["ssid"] = WiFi.SSID(i);
    }
    serializeJsonPretty(jsonDoc, SerialBT);
    serializeJsonPretty(jsonDoc, Serial);
}
```

This should produce a JSON document that looks like this:

```
{
  "wifiList": [
    { "ssid": "quark" },
    { "ssid": "Airtel_Zerotouch" },
    { "ssid": "NETGEAR77" },
    { "ssid": "Itobuz-technologies" },
    { "ssid": "Nokia 6.1" }
  ]
}
```

---

**Edit**: Note that, if it's clear from the context (e.g. a request URL)
that you are transmitting a list of WiFi networks, then you can get rid
of the outer object and the "wifiList" label, and use the array as the
JSON document:

```
[
  { "ssid": "quark" },
  { "ssid": "Airtel_Zerotouch" },
  { "ssid": "NETGEAR77" },
  { "ssid": "Itobuz-technologies" },
  { "ssid": "Nokia 6.1" }
]
```

As suggested by Jaromanda X, if you are never going to extend the inner
objects with extra information, you can further simplify the document by
removing those objects and just listing the SSIDs in the array:

```
[
  "quark",
  "Airtel_Zerotouch",
  "NETGEAR77",
  "Itobuz-technologies",
  "Nokia 6.1"
]
```

Comment: Thank you. The array concept was not clear to me.

Comment: since all objects in the array are *ssid* - you can further simplify (and shrink) the output by changing `wifiList` to an array of just the ssid strings

Comment: @JaromandaX: Indeed – edited the answer. I initially assumed the OP might want to later add other properties to the entries (signal strength, channel...).